# how to connect telegesis ETRX2 USB stick using c#

Tags: c#, zigbee

i am trying to connect the USB stick by using the following commands:

```
string arr="AT+JN";
serialport1.open();
serialport1.write(arr);
```

but still i cant join any PAN